# What exactly does the term "gram atoms" mean?

Tags: stoichiometry, terminology

[The Wikipedia article on the mole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mole_(unit)) states:

> The term **gram-atom** (abbreviated gat.) has been used for a related but distinct concept, namely a quantity of a substance that contains Avogadro's number of atoms, whether isolated or combined in molecules. Thus, for example, 1 mole of $\ce{MgB2}$ is 1 gram-molecule of $\ce{MgB2}$ but 3 gram-atoms of $\ce{MgB2}$.

Can anybody explain the difference between moles and gram atoms, and how is it that *1 mole of $\ce{MgB2}$ is 1 gram-molecule of $\ce{MgB2}$ but 3 gram-atoms of $\ce{MgB2}$*?

Comment: The molecule has 3 atoms, so ......

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\ce{MgB2}$ is 1 gram-molecule of $\ce{MgB2}$ but 3 gram-atoms of $\ce{MgB2}$.

Why is this so? Let us consider this problem in the familiar mole:

If we were asked how many moles of the substance (molecule) were in this, we would state 1 mole, if there were $\pu{45.3 g}$ of substance. However, if we were asked how many moles of atoms were in the substance, we would accordingly state 3. Thus, in one molecule, there are 3 atoms, so if we simply consider the number of atoms, there would be the necessity of counting the number. of atoms in a molecule, as a molecule is comprised of more than a single atom

* This is purely hypothetical. One would probably not consider  $\ce{MgB2}$, as J. LS pointed out, it decomposes . However, the concept can be applied to other compounds

Comment: There are no molecules of magnesium diboride as it decomposes before you can reach its melting point, which makes this a rather odd example to use here.

Comment: @J.LS Thanks for pointing that out! I had simply used the example the asker had given, but I guess it would be nice to be aware of that point.

Comment: OP has also asked for difference between moles and gram atoms ,but nobody explained this point?