# How to calculate the charge on 1 gram ions Aluminum cation?

Tags: mole

I want to find out the charge on 1 gram ions of $\ce{Al^3+}$ ions.

I tried out by finding no. of moles as $ \frac{1}{27} $ , then no. of ions will be $ \frac{1}{27} × N_A $ ,

then total charge will be $ \frac{1}{27} × N_A × 3e $ but it is wrong.

The correct answer turns out to be  $ N_A × 3e $ .

Where I am wrong?

[ $ e $ = charge on 1 electron, $ N_A $ = Avogadro's Number ]

Comment: @RaviPrakash What you did is perfectly correct. Who told you it's wrong?

Comment: @PrittBalagopal Yes it seems to be correct but the answer is 3 $ N_A e $

Comment: They must've meant "one mole", not "one gram". Btw I didn't downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - gram ions is same as 1 mole.

So, we need to find only the charge on 1 mole of ions, i.e.,

$ N_A × 3e $ colulomb.

Comment: Related https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/28563/what-exactly-does-the-term-gram-atoms-mean